# Show $1_V$ and $M$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

$M: V \rightarrow V$ a linear operator s.t. $M^2 + 1_v = 0$

1. $V$ is REAL vector space, show $1_v$ and $M$ are linearly independent
2. if $V$ and $M$ are complex, show $1_v$ and $M$ need NOT be linearly independent
3. find the possibilities for minimal poly of $M^3+2M^2+M+3\cdot 1_v$

---

my work/thought (you can ignore this, they are most likely wrong).

1) need to show $a\cdot 1_v + b \cdot M = 0$ has only trivial solution i.e. $a = b = 0$

OR, i cannot write one as a scalar multiple of other,

i.e. $c\cdot M = 1_v$ cannot hold

I'm given $M (-M) = 1_v$; since $M$ is not scalar, can I conclude $1_v$ and $M$ are linearly independent?

2) I'm not sure how those two being complex chances anything. I figure it has something to do with minimum polynomial

$u(x) = t^2 + 1$
$u(M) = M^2 + 1 = 0$
$M = \pm i$

and $i (-i) = 1_v$ so they're linearly dependent?
But this shows that they're always dependent. The question says "need not be linearly dependent".

3) given $M^2 = -1_v$ I can rewrite polynom as

$M^3 +L + 1_v$

would min polynom be $u(x) = x^3-x-1$? what are other possibilities?

Comment: For 2), the question says to show that they need not be linearly INdependent, which is what you've attempted to show.

Answer (score 1):

$M$ is a linear transformation. $M^2+1=0$ doesn't imply $M=\pm i$. However, the linear transformation $\Bbb C^{1\times 1}\to\Bbb C^{1\times 1}$ with $z\mapsto iz$ **is** a counterexample to $M$ and $1$ being linearly independent in the complex case.

For the last one, note $M^3=MM^2=M(-1)=-M$, so $M^3+2M^2+M+3I$ equals $-M-2I+M+3I=I$, thus the minimal polynomial of $M^3+2M^2+M+3I$ is $X-1$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), you are on the right track: we want to show that $M$ is not equal to $c1_V$ for some real number $c$. The easiest way to see this is to suppose the opposite were true: that $M=c1_V$ for some real number $c$. But if that were true, then $(c1_V)^2+1_V=(c^2+1)1_V=0$. Can such a $c$ exist?

For (2), the point is that we could choose $M=i 1_V$ for $i=\sqrt{-1}$, and it would satisfy the equation $M^2+1_V=0$. However, this $M$ is not linearly independent from $1_V$, since it is a multiple of $1_V$!

For (3), $M^2=-1_V$, so $M^3=-M$. Then $M^3+2M^2+M+31_V=-M-21_V+M+31_V=1_V$. What is the minimal polynomial of the identity?